# How do I tweak the HTML markup of an image?

Tags: media

I want to edit the `alt` tag for several images on my Drupal site.

But Drupal just lets me upload and place the images.

How do I access the html for the images?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Structure > Content type > Your content type > Manage Fields > Your image fields > Edit**. There are the **Enable Alt field** and **Enable Title field** checkboxes; select them, and you will have access to the meta data in your node/add form.

Comment: Excellent! This exactly the solution I needed.